# controlling the content available to wordpress users(not admin)

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with another user besides the admin. I want this user to see the forms that has been submitted. I have two kinds of forms but for some reason the user see only the submissions from one post. Unfortunately i couldn't find anywhere how to manage this visibilities,  anyone knows how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Are these two forms using a different plugin?
I use this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) (User Role Editor) to manage user rights.

Cheers,

Bram